# Modifying text in the console using Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, printing, console

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of modifying the text in the console. For example: if I am keeping  track of the number of events that have occurred, I'll print

```
0 events have occurred
```

and as events occur I want to increment that 0.

Currently I am doing that in a very ugly way:
Keep track of everything printed to the console using a String or Stringbuilder and if I need to make any changes, change the string, clear the console, print the string to the console. Aside from probably not being very efficient, it displays in an ugly way resulting in the console's "blinking" when too many changes are made in a short period of time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use the carriage return code. This basically returns the cursor to the beginning of the same line. This is different from the carriage return + line feed (vbCrLf), which puts the cursor at the beginning of the next line.

There are slightly different ways to do this in VB vs. C#.

- VB: Use the vbCr code.
- C#: Use the \r code.

Here's some sample code:

VB:

```
For i = 1 To 100
    Console.Write("Processing...{0}% complete  " & vbCr, i)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
Next
```

C#:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Processing... {0}% complete\r", i);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Comment: Let me elaborate a bit, I also need to move the line up and down (i.e. if an error is printed, I want to keep the "processing..." line on the bottom at all times. This means that if an error occurs, I need to clear the last line of the console (unless the last line printed is an error line), and then print the processing line again.)

Comment: I think this might be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804233/c-how-to-modify-previous-line-of-console-text