# How can I edit text that has already been printed in Console in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, console, console-application

This question is certainly a duplicate: I remember reading the answer years ago. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find the link either by searching SO or Google, so I'm forced to ask again. Apologies.

What I'm trying to do is print text in a Console application, which the user can then edit and modify, and then press Enter to change the value of. I know that I can intercept the user's keypresses, determine intelligently what to do with them, and use `Console.SetCursorPosition` to dynamically change the text.

However, I know for sure that there was a hacky one line solution I read on an answer ages ago (which worked, but was not recommended,) and I can't remember what it was.

Does anyone know what this solution is, or have a link to the post I'm looking for?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371146/modifying-text-in-the-console-using-visual-basic) method to achieve that?

Comment: Yep, that's basically how I normally do this. I'm looking for a different method.

Comment: Probably I've found a good solution for you. Better use `Console.Clear()` to update the line by clearing the entire texts. Because the problem is, I've tried all possible methods for your problem (`vbCr`, `vbBack`, `Console.SetCursorPosition()`, etc.) but they're not useful. They can replace to the string length weirdly. For example: `abcd` can be updated to `abcde`. BUT If you want to change into lesser length, e.g. "abcxyz" to "def", it'll print "defxyz" (xyz not updated).

Comment: I know how to do this too, this isn't the solution I'm looking for unfortunately. There's a one or two line code that allows you to print text and then modify it, which I've seen on SO before but lost the link.

Comment: From the one above, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804233/how-to-modify-the-previous-line-of-console-text).  It's only a couple lines a matter of Insert text at X, Y

Comment: Hi @JimmySmith, none of the three answers on the question you've linked to seem to have the solution I'm looking for unfortunately. The first uses Console.SetCursorPosition, the second appears to do a complex solution also involving Console.SetCursorPosition, and the last uses a carriage return. There was definitely a method which did not resemble any of these.

Comment: I'm confused as to what that method would be, are you aware of the classes it utilized?   as the one I saw with the SetCursorPosition and overwrites the text was like 2 lines, I believe.

Comment: I'm not aware, sadly. All I remember was that it's a janky method that's not advised because it can lead to errors of some kind. I would love to know where I saw this question.