# Clear the current line, as with fflush(stdout) in C

Tags: c#, console, fflush

I have a very long for loop, which prints out many lines of information. I would like to keep it to just one line that overwrites previous lines. I tried Console.out.flush() but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Most likely you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804233/how-to-modify-the-previous-line-of-console-text

Comment: Side note: Yang, could you please link to what part of "flush" behavior of the `fflush` method you want to replicate? Not everyone using C# is familiar with C runtime... Also about "keep just one line" - do you mean something like `Console.Clear` or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946808/can-console-clear-be-used-to-only-clear-a-line-instead-of-whole-console?

Comment: These are exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Console.SetCursorPosition
```

to get where the Cursor is at use

```
Console.CursorLeft
Console.CursorTop
```

Example

```
int i = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Numbers will count below this line");

int cLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
int cTop = Console.CursorTop;

while (true)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(cLeft, cTop);
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Not yet sure if it is answer - consider editing post to clarify what exact interpretation of the question you are answering. Note that I've already linked to exactly the same suggestion - it is not yet clear what OP looking for, otherwise would be duplicate already.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Since OP has accepted this answer, I'd say it *is* a duplicate.